# WCAG Accessibility Issue with React-Bootstrap - Nav bar issue

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using the 'axe' extension for Chrome (Accessibility testing in Chrome Developer Tools)

It's reporting that:

```
<ul> and <ol> must only directly contain <li>, <script> or <template> elements
```

I'm constructing my nav bar using React-bootstrap,

```
  <div>
    <Nav pullRight>
      <LinkContainer to="/survey">
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/survey">
          Start Survey
        </NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>

      <LinkContainer to="/login">
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/login">
          Log In
        </NavItem>
      </LinkContainer>
    </Nav>
  </div>
```

which is generating the following HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="/survey">Start Survey</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
    <a href="/login">Log In</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```